# Set default zoom in Excel on a new sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-office, macros

I have set zoom level when new workbook is open with this code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 109

End Sub
```

How to I set custom zoom on every new sheet that's created in that workbook?

Answer (score 0):

You may intercept the creation event of a new sheet in exactly
the same way as you did for the workbook.

The NewSheet event is triggered when you insert a new sheet in the
workbook. You can use similar code to this (I didn't test):

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
On Error Resume Next
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 109
End Sub
```

For more information see
[Workbook.NewSheet event (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.newsheet).